# Sonarqube, i dont understand how it measure the test coverage

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, gradlew

im new to sonarqube and i don't get how it works.
I clone this example project:
https://github.com/tkgregory/sonarqube-jacoco-code-coverage

as is, the project has a 66% of code coverage, so i added a dummy class and it droped down to 33.
i added this line:
   `property 'sonar.coverage.exclusions', 'src/main/java/com/tom/service/MartinDTO.java'`
to exclude the class i added, and the coverage goes up to 66 again.

then i remove all the tests and the coverage still in 66, and it should be zero because it has no tests!

Can someone with best understanding explain me how this work ? i just need to exclude all the DTOs of a project.

**Set up and make it run:**

im following this example
https://tomgregory.com/how-to-measure-code-coverage-using-sonarqube-and-jacoco/#2_A_worked_example

clone this proyect:
`https://github.com/tkgregory/sonarqube-jacoco-code-coverage`

I started up a local sonar with:

`./gradlew composeUp`

inside the example project (you need to have docker installed for this to work).

to send information to the dockerSonar just run

`./gradlew sonarqube`

keep in mind all of these is configured inside the example project.

Thx!

Comment: Are you running `./gradlew clean` prior to checking code coverage again?

Answer (score 2):

Everything up to *"then i remove all the tests and the coverage still in 66, and it should be zero because it has no tests!"* seems like desired behaviour to me. Correct me if I'm wrong.

**What happens when you delete all the tests though?**

Well, you can run the *sonarqube* Gradle task with verbose output to see what tasks are being executed.

```
$ ./gradlew  sonarqube --console=verbose 
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test
> Task :jacocoTestReport SKIPPED
> Task :sonarqube
...
```

Importantly the *jacocoTestReport* task is skipped. This is responsible for generating the XML report.

This means:

1. the old XML report remains
2. the old XML report gets sent to SonarQube
3. the incorrect coverage percentage is shown in SonarQube

This happens because of the way the *jacocoTestReport* task is written. If there's no test execution data (which is the case here as there are no tests) the task gets skipped.

You can read more about this behaviour in [this bug report](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18271), where I've also followed up about this specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

The sonar scanner itself doesn't measure code coverage, it just imports the coverage report generated by jacoco when the tests were executed. If you just run "./gradlew sonarqube" it will import your existing coverage report instead of generating an updated one.
Most likely you need to run this instead:

```
./gradlew clean build sonarqube
```